# How to sum two different queries and group them?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

| amount | from_client | to_client | transaction_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | NA | Jacques | tsa |
| 400 | John | NA | tsb |
| 800 | John | NA | tsb |
| 800 | NA | Jacques | tsa |
| 100 | Jacques | NA | tsb |

I would like to get the sum of Jacques and John transactions in a single column whether it's a tsa or tsb, like this:

| total_transactions | clients |
| --- | --- |
| 1100 | John |
| 1200 | Jacques |

how could I do this on thousands of transactions while grouping by customer names? THANKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be using union all.

With the given data example as follows

```
create table test (
  amount int,
  from_client varchar(25)  ,
  to_client varchar(25)  ,
  transaction_type varchar(5)  );

insert into test values
(200,'NA','Jacques','tsa'),
(400,'John','NA','tsb'),
(800,'John','NA','tsb'),
(800,'NA','Jacques','tsa'),
(100,'Jacques','NA','tsb');
```

Query,

```
select sum(from_client_amount) as total_transactions,
       from_client as clients
from (select sum(amount) as  from_client_amount,from_client
      from test
      where from_client in ('John','Jacques')  
      group by from_client  
    union all
     select sum(amount) as  to_client_amount,to_client
     from test
     where to_client in ('John','Jacques')  
     group by to_client  
    ) tbl 
group by   clients;
```

> Result
>
> ```
> total_transactions    clients
>     1200              John
>     1100              Jacques
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SP_i1dA1)

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly simpler and works for an arbitrary number of clients:

```
create table test (
  amount int,
  from_client varchar(25)  ,
  to_client varchar(25)  ,
  transaction_type varchar(5)  );

insert into test values
(200,'NA','Jacques','tsa'),
(400,'John','NA','tsb'),
(800,'John','NA','tsb'),
(800,'NA','Jacques','tsa'),
(100,'Jacques','NA','tsb');
```

```
SELECT from_client, SUM(from_client_amount)
FROM
(
select sum(amount) as  from_client_amount,from_client
      from test
      where from_client != 'NA'
      group by from_client  
    union all
     select sum(amount) as  to_client_amount,to_client
     from test
     where to_client != 'NA'  
     group by to_client 
) AS t
GROUP BY from_client;
```

[*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/ri-roqII) - [Vérace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34007/v%C3%A9race)